# \columncolor in foreground if use \multirow

Tags: tables, multirow, backgrounds, colortbl

It seems that if I use `>{\columncolor{green!30}}c` *and* have `\multirow` content in that column, the color ends up in the foreground.

The only difference in these two tables is that the second one has `>{\columncolor{green!30}}` applied to the first column and the first table does not.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcommand*{\MyTabelContent}{%
        \toprule
        &$+$ & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 
        \\
        \multirow{6}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Label}}
         &0 & & & & & &
        \\
         &1 & & & & & &
        \\
         &2 & & & & & &
        \\
         &3 & & & & & &
        \\
         &4 & & & & & &
        \\
         &5 & & & & & &
        \\
        \bottomrule
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
    \begin{tabular}{c >{\columncolor{cyan!30}}cccccc c @{}}
        \MyTabelContent
    \end{tabular}
    \quad
    \begin{tabular}{>{\columncolor{green!30}}c >{\columncolor{cyan!30}}cccccc c @{}}
        \MyTabelContent
    \end{tabular}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use multirow in the bottom most cell and specify a negative number of rows.

Comment: @Skillmon: Yep that works. I guess this is a _known_ issue as I don't recall hearing that the `\multirow` must be at the end.

Comment: The issue is that cell colours are applied once a cell is started, but multirow is applied the moment you use it so every following cell might overprint the area `\multirow` prints in (`\multirow` is really just something like `\raisebox{<somelength>}{...}`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get what you want by using `\multirow` in the bottom most row and specifying a negative count of rows.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % also loads colortbl
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcommand*{\MyTabelContent}{%
        \toprule
        &$+$ & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 
        \\
         &0 & & & & & &
        \\
         &1 & & & & & &
        \\
         &2 & & & & & &
        \\
         &3 & & & & & &
        \\
         &4 & & & & & &
        \\
        \multirow{-6}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Label}}
         &5 & & & & & &
        \\
        \bottomrule
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
    \begin{tabular}{c >{\columncolor{cyan!30}}cccccc c @{}}
        \MyTabelContent
    \end{tabular}
    \quad
    \begin{tabular}{>{\columncolor{green!30}}c >{\columncolor{cyan!30}}cccccc c @{}}
        \MyTabelContent
    \end{tabular}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, but I would replace `\usepackage{xcolor}\usepackage{colortbl}` with `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` :-)

Comment: @Zarko indeed. The preamble was copied from the OP, but best to show best practice here, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (and the key `colortbl-like`), you have directly the expected result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\newcommand*{\MyTabelContent}{%
        \toprule
        &$+$ & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 
        \\
        \multirow{6}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Label}}
         &0 & & & & & &
        \\
         &1 & & & & & &
        \\
         &2 & & & & & &
        \\
         &3 & & & & & &
        \\
         &4 & & & & & &
        \\
         &5 & & & & & &
        \\
        \bottomrule
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
    \begin{NiceTabular}{c >{\columncolor{cyan!30}}ccccccc@{}}[colortbl-like]
        \MyTabelContent
    \end{NiceTabular}
    \quad
    \begin{NiceTabular}{>{\columncolor{green!30}}c >{\columncolor{cyan!30}}ccccccc@{}}[colortbl-like]
        \MyTabelContent
    \end{NiceTabular}%
\end{document}
```

The colored panels extend until the rules of `booktabs` by desing of `nicematrix`.

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]